# Why does the first size of the GeometryReader's closure parameter in the .task modifier have a value of 0 and how can I fix it?

Tags: swiftui, task, size, geometryreader

I'm creating an app that shows a list of items on the main screen, and images and details of the selected item in a DetailView.

In order to minimize the memory usage of the image, I am downsampling the size value of the GeometryReader's closure parameter in the .task modifier of the DetailView, but the first time I get the size value, the width and height values are all 0, so I can't see the image.

When I debugged it, I saw that I was getting the first 0 value and then the correct value, so I confirmed that the image is visible through the .task(id: size) modifier, but I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do it.

I'd appreciate it if you could tell me why the size.width, size.height values I'm getting at first are all 0 and if what I've done is the right way to do it, and should I always downsample the image?

```
struct ContextView: View {
    @State private var seletedItem: Item?
    var body: some View {
        MainListView()
            .sheet(item: $seletedItem) { item in
                GeometryProxy { proxy in
                    let size = proxy.size // 
                    DetailImageView(item: item, size: size)
                        .ignoresSafeArea(.container, edges: .top)

                }
            }
    }
}

struct DetailImageView: View {
    var item: Item
    var size: CGSize
    @State private var uiImage: UIImage? = nil

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            GeometryReader { proxy in
                let childSize = proxy.size
                if let uiImage {
                    Image(uiImage: uiImage)
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .frame(width: childSize.width, height: childSize.height)
                }
            }
            .frame(height: size.height)
        }
        .coordinateSpace(name: "scroll")
        .task {
            // ❌ not show Image, not working 
            // size.width = 0, size.height = 0
            uiImage = downsampleImage(imageData: item.imageData,
                                      to: CGSize(width: size.width, height: size.height))
        }
        .task(id: size) {
            // ✅ show Image, working 
            uiImage = downsampleImage(imageData: item.imageData,
                                      to: CGSize(width: size.width, height: size.height))
        }
    }

    private func downsampleImage(imageData: Data, to pointSize: CGSize, scale: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.scale) -> UIImage {
        let imageSourceOptions = [kCGImageSourceShouldCache: false] as CFDictionary
        guard let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(imageData as CFData, imageSourceOptions) else { return UIImage() }

        let maxDimensionInPixels = max(pointSize.width, pointSize.height) * scale
        let downsampleOptions = [
            kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageAlways: true,
            kCGImageSourceShouldCacheImmediately: true,
            kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform: true,
            kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize: maxDimensionInPixels
        ] as CFDictionary

        guard let downsampledImage = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(imageSource, 0, downsampleOptions) else { return UIImage() }
        return UIImage(cgImage: downsampledImage)
    }
}
```

I use .task(id: size) modifier to when size has changed re draw body property

+++++

```
@State private var isSizeZero = true

...

if isSizeZero {
     ProgressView()
}  else {
     if let uiImage {
                    Image(uiImage: uiImage)
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                }
}
.frame(width: childSize.width, height: childSize.height)

...

.task(id: size) {
            if size == 0 {
               isSizeZero = true
               return
            } else {
            uiImage = downsampleImage(imageData: item.imageData,
                                      to: CGSize(width: size.width, height: size.height))
            isSizeZero = false
        }
```

right???

Comment: It’s not broken, if you don’t want to run code when it is zero just guard against it, show a progress view or something for that frame

Comment: You mean to show the ProgressView when the size value is zero, so should I control the ProgressView with a Bool type variable? I'm not sure where to implement this logic.

Comment: In the else for the if you have. And the guard where the green checkmark is now if zero return

Comment: I've added what you told me to the body, could you take a look?

Comment: No no no leave the “if let” as is just add the “else”. The guard is literal, something like “guard size != .zero else {return}”

Comment: I'm running English through a translator, so I don't understand exactly what you're saying. 

I want to implement it so that the image is displayed correctly with the .task modifier, without using the task(id:) modifier, but with the task(id: size), so that it detects that the size changes and re-renders the image when it's not a zero value?

When I use .task, I only get an empty image.

Comment: It won’t be possible with task, that only runs once, you have to listen for changes.

Comment: Aha thanks, I was wondering if there might be some unnecessary performance as the body has to be redrawn once until the size value gets a value from 0.

Comment: Before downsampling the image, in .task(id:) added guard size != .zero else { return }. Now it shows the default image when size is 0 and then shows the downsampled image when the size value changes, which causes an unnatural animation on the screen. Can I ask for any advice?